# Check if QVariantAnimation is finished?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, signals, slot

I have a class derived from `QVariantAnimation` and I have to run a code after the finish of the animation.

I tried the signal `finished()` yet, but there is no emit:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(setEndVariables()));
```

Is there any other opinion to see if the animation is stopped, or is the usage of the signal wrong?

Edit: with Code

```
LiConfigurableFrameAnimation::LiConfigurableFrameAnimation(QString compId, int dur, LiConfigurableFrame *f)
{
    if(dur>0)
        this->setDuration(dur);
    frame=f;
    widget=frame->getComponent(compId);
    isRectMode=false;
    isImageMode=false;

    connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(setEndVariables()));
}
```

Header File:

```
class LiConfigurableFrameAnimation: public QVariantAnimation
{

    private slots:
        void setEndVariables();

    };
```

Comment: Why are both the signal and the slot in the same object (`this`)? Shouldn't it be something like `connect( <pointer_to_QVariantAnimation_object>, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(setEndVariables()));`?

Comment: But i make the connect in my overwritten QVariantAnimation class, so I think it is is ok to use the same object (this)? Or am I wrong and this isn't possible? thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yes, in this case it is fine, I just wanted to check if it is a typo. Did you overload `start` or any other functions? Also, you can call `state()` at any time to check if the animation is still running.

Comment: Yes i overload the updateCurrentValue function. I tried to change the slot to another slot from an other object. Now it is working and the signal is emitted. It seems that you are not able to use the same object on the signal and the slot.

Comment: no, it is definitely and absolutely possible to connect an object's signals to it's own slots. It's hard to tell why exactly it happened to you without seeing the code, though.

Comment: I have added some code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

I overload the function updateCurrentTime and check if the current time is equal to the duration.

```
updateCurrentTime(int curr)
{

    if(curr >= this->duration())....
...
```